# NameError en la ejecucion de un programo utilizando formula

Tags: python, python-3.x

primero que todo disculpas,soy nuevo en esto de programar.

He hecho un programa en Python donde te pide una fecha y la has de escribir en Formato DD/MM/AAAA, aparte de esto la fecha año esta limitada entre los años (2000-2100), también teniendo en cuanta los años bisiestos, febrero tiene 28 días y no 29.

El problema es que cuando lo ejecuto me pide la fecha, pero luego se genera un error ( **NameError: name 'errorInDate' is not defined** ) que esta en la linia 3 (**cuando llamo a la funcio que he generado**) y no se a que se debe. si alguien me pudiera ayudar.

muchas gracias,

```
data = str(input("escribe fecha DD/MM/AAAA: "))  # introduccón de dades

errcod= errorInDate(data)        #llamo a la función

print(errorInSeatTbl[errcod])
print("fi del programa")

def errorInDate(Data):
    FormatoData="DD/MM/AAAA"
if len(Data)==len(FormatoData):

    if Data[:2].isdigit() and Data[3:5].isdigit() and Data[6:].isdigit:
        DiesMes = [0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]       #para los bisiestos.
        dia = int(data[:2])
        mes = int(data[3:5])
        any = int(data[6:])

        if any >= 2000 and any <= 2100:
            if not (any % 4==0 and any%100!=0 or any%400==0):
                DiesMes [2]=28                                  #cuando es un año bisiesto febrero tiene 28 dias.

            if mes >= 1 and mes <= 12:
                if DiesMes[mes] >= dia and dia > 0:
                    errcod=0

                else: errcod=1
            else: errcod=2
        else: errcod=3
    else: errcod=4
else: errcod=5

return errcod
errorInSeatTbl = ["Data vàlid.",                        #errcod==0
                  "Número de dia incorrecte.",          #errcod==1
                  "Número de mes inexistent.",          #errcod==2
                  "Número d’any fora del rang permès.", #errcod==3
                  "Format incorrecte.",                 #errcod==4
                  "Longitud del text incorrecta."]      #errcod==5
```

el mensaje de error que se me genera es el siguiente:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/……...", line 3, in <module>
    error= errorInDate(data)
NameError: name 'errorInDate' is not defined****
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que te muestra se debe a que no encuentra la función `errorInDate()`, los programas en Python y otros lenguajes de programación se ejecutan de arriba hacia abajo, es por eso que debes definir la función antes de utilizarla. Lo mismo pasaría con la lista `errorInSeatTbl`.

```
data = str(input("escribe fecha DD/MM/AAAA: "))  # introduccón de dades

def errorInDate(Data):
    FormatoData="DD/MM/AAAA"
    if len(Data)==len(FormatoData):
        if Data[:2].isdigit() and Data[3:5].isdigit() and Data[6:].isdigit:
            DiesMes = [0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]       #para los bisiestos.
            dia = int(data[:2])
            mes = int(data[3:5])
            any = int(data[6:])

            if any >= 2000 and any <= 2100:
                if not (any % 4==0 and any%100!=0 or any%400==0):
                    DiesMes [2]=28                                  #cuando es un año bisiesto febrero tiene 28 dias.

                if mes >= 1 and mes <= 12:
                    if DiesMes[mes] >= dia and dia > 0:
                        errcod=0

                    else: errcod=1
                else: errcod=2
            else: errcod=3
        else: errcod=4
    else: errcod=5
    return errcod

errorInSeatTbl = ["Data vàlid.",                        #errcod==0
                  "Número de dia incorrecte.",          #errcod==1
                  "Número de mes inexistent.",          #errcod==2
                  "Número d’any fora del rang permès.", #errcod==3
                  "Format incorrecte.",                 #errcod==4
                  "Longitud del text incorrecta."]      #errcod==5

errcod= errorInDate(data)        #llamo a la función

print(errorInSeatTbl[errcod])
print("fi del programa")
```

Comment: He puesto la lista y la función arriba, después de la entrada de dadas, y ahora funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias